# Hibernate ignores @MapsId in @ManyToOne relation and still attempts to persist parent

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

In JPA, I have three entities:

1. Absence
2. AbsenceAffectation
3. Branch

Where AbsenceAffectation is a sort of pivot table between three tables: Absence, User, and Branch. Given that it is a mostly unidirectional pivot table, I have defined it as so:

```java
@Entity
@Table
public class AbsenceAffectation implements Serializable {
    @Data
    @Embeddable
    public static class CompositeKey implements Serializable {
        @Column(name = "user_id")
        private Integer userId;
        @Column(name = "branch_code")
        private String branchCode;
        @Column(name = "absence_id")
        private Integer absenceId;
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    CompositeKey id = new CompositeKey();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @MapsId("userId")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "branch_code")
    @MapsId("branchCode")
    private Branch branch;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "absence_id")
    @MapsId("absenceId")
    private Absence absence;

...
```

The Branch class:

```java
@Entity
@Table
public class Branch {
    @Id
    private String code;
...
```

The Absence class:

```java
@Entity
@Table
public class Absence {
    ...

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    ...
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "absence")
    private List<AbsenceAffectation> replacements;
    ...
```

However, I get the following error: `org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [Branch#tsthww5]` when saving an absence. Examination in a debugger shows it is the AbsenceAffectation trying to save the branch, even though it shouldn't since it is annotated with @MapsId.

In my test, I start by saving all the relations (users, **branches**, and other widgets, but not the AbsenceAffectations).

```java
    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void testSaveMapping() {
        Absence absence = absenceGenerator.generate();
        absenceTestUtils.persistRelations(absence);
        absenceRepository.save(absence);
        assertNotNull(absence.getId());
    }
```

The exception occurs when trying to save the absence. It says that the branch is already saved and in the session (as expected) due to the call to `persistRelations`. What isn't expected however is that Hibernate tried to cascade the @ManyToOne relation in the AbsenceAffectation.

Proof in the debugger that Hibernate is trying to cascade the relation:

[image: Debugger proof]

Hence: how can I stop Hibernate from trying to persist my @ManyToOne relation from AbsenceAffectation -> Branch and just store its code?